# Overriding the order of fields in serializer response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this class `Meta`:

```
class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = (
        'brand', 'currency', 'order_id', 'reference_id', 'ordered_date',
        'amount', 'quantity', 'order_status', 'app_code', 'vouchers')
```

I want to change the ordering of `field` on response(serializer).

Changing the ordering in the class `Meta` did not work.
I have also tried the `to_representation` method with no success.